# Not able to add existing storage account to enable diagnostic logs during azure VM creation using farmer

Tags: azure, f#, azure-resource-manager

The Farmer library has builder for Virtual machine creation, though it has support for parameter "diagnostics_support_external" which enables the boot diagnostics with existing created storage account.

```ml
let storageAccount =  LinkedResource.Unmanaged resourceId
vm {
  diagnostics_support_external storageAccount
}
```

But it generates the incorrect arm template.
Currently it generates the arm template with following property attached to it.

```
"properties": {
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[reference('sa0ce3c1e410a5ec454941').primaryEndpoints.blob]"
          }
        },
```

The above generated templates fail to create resources as Azure complains with following error

```
{
  "code": "InvalidTemplate",
  "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template reference 'sa0ce3c1e410a5ec454941' is not valid: could not find template resource or resource copy with this name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.'."
}
```

The correct template should look like this, as after this modification Azure is able to resolve the Storage Account resource.

```
"diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', 'sa0ce3c1e410a5ec454941'),'2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints.blob]"
          }
        },
```

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Farmer library, the team is resolving it. This fix is targeted for version 1.7.4.
https://github.com/CompositionalIT/farmer/pull/945